# Handover function as parameter that has parameters

Tags: c++

I want to pass a callback function that has a parameter:

```
class foo1{
    foo1(void (*callback)(float));
};
foo1::foo1(void (*callback)(float)){
    //execute the callback at some point
}

float foo2(){
    return 1.1;
}
void foo3(float f){
    //do stuff with f
    return;
}
int main(){
    void (*p3)(float); 
//p3 is a pointer to a function that returns void and has a single float as input
    p3 = &foo3(foo2()); 
//p3 now points to foo3 which fits the requirements. But it does not make sense to give that pointer an argument. 
    
    foo1(p3);
    return 0;
}
```

There are several errors and I understand that this does not make sense. (See comments in the code) But I don't know how to do it correctly. I want to pass a function as callback that has the input value of foo2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something more like this instead:

```
class foo1 {
    foo1(void (*callback)(float));
};
```

```
float foo2();

foo1::foo1(void (*callback)(float)) {
    //excecute the callback at some point
    callback(foo2());
}
```

```
float foo2() {
    return 1.1;
}

void foo3(float f) {
    //do stuff with f
}

int main() {
    void (*p3)(float); 
    p3 = &foo3; 
    foo1(p3);

    // or simply:
    // foo1(&foo3);

    return 0;
}
```

If you do not want `foo1()` passing a parameter value to the callback, then don't declare the callback with an input parameter to begin with, use another callback function that calls the intended callback function:

```
class foo1 {
    foo1(void (*callback)());
};

foo1::foo1(void (*callback)()) {
    //excecute the callback at some point
    callback();
}
```

```
float foo2() {
    return 1.1;
}

void foo3(float f) {
    //do stuff with f
}

void foo4() {
    foo3(foo2());
}

int main() {
    void (*p4)(); 
    p4 = &foo4; 
    foo1(p4);

    // or simply:
    // foo1(&foo4);

    return 0;
}
```

Or, in C++11 and later, you can use a lambda:

```
class foo1 {
    template<class T>
    foo1(T callback) {
        //excecute the callback at some point
        callback();
    }
};

Or:

#include <functional>

class foo1 {
    foo1(std::function<void()> callback) {
        //excecute the callback at some point
        callback();
    }
};
```

```
float foo2() {
    return 1.1;
}

void foo3(float f) {
    //do stuff with f
}

int main() {
    foo1([](){ foo3(foo2()); });
    return 0;
}
```

Or, you can use [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
class foo1 {
    template <typename T>
    foo1(T callback) {
        //excecute the callback at some point
        callback();
    }
};

or:

#include <functional>

class foo1 {
    foo1(std::function<void()> callback) {
        //excecute the callback at some point
        callback();
    }
};
```

```
#include <functional>

float foo2() {
    return 1.1;
}

void foo3(float f) {
    //do stuff with f
}

int main() {
    foo1(std::bind(foo3, foo2()));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank for this very detailed answer! As you two (@skypjack) both recommended the lambda way, I'll try that one for now. I now get the error `error: expected type-specifier before 'foo1'
   anotherFoo(new foo1(other parameters, []() {`

Comment: It compiles also in the arduino ide. So the error must be somewhere deeper in my actual code. I guess my question is answered then. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda to do that.
Something along this way should work:

```
struct foo1{
    template<typename F>
    foo1(F f) {
        //excecute the callback at some point
        f();
    }
};

float foo2(){
    return 1.1;
}

void foo3(float){
    //do stuff with f
    return;
}

int main(){
    foo1([param{foo2()}](){ foo3(param); });
}
```

Consider this expression:

```
[param{foo2()}](){ foo3(param); }
```

It creates a callable object having type `void(void)`, that is what you expected by applying the result of the execution of `foo2` at the first argument of `foo3` (right?).
That's why you can simply invoke it as `f()` within the constructor of `foo1`.

Comment: is there a way to keep foo1 a class? I need to create objects of it

Comment: @user7408924 `foo1` **is** a class. If you prefer to use the `class` keyword, use this: `class foo1 { public: /* the same body you can see in the example */ };`.

Comment: I am not familiar with that syntax. "use this: ... /*the same body...*/" means like this: `class foo1{
    foo1(void (*callback)(float));
};
template<typename F>
foo1::foo1(F f){
    //excecute the callback at some point
}`? EDIT: of course the declaration of foo1 should also have the type (F f) as input...

Comment: @user7408924 No, this: `class foo1{ public: template<typename F> foo1(F f) { //excecute the callback at some point f(); } };`.

Comment: If I put this into my original code I get the error it asks me to  #include <initializer_list>. I don't think that initializer_list is a real library (can't find it). Any Idea what it could mean?

Comment: @user7408924 `initializer_list` is part of the standard template library. You should study a bit more the language before to adventure within it. That being said, I don't know why it ask it. Can you provide a minimal example to reproduce the error?

Comment: Do you think it could be because I am using an arduino. Some c++ features are not supported by the arduino compiler. I'll do my best to reproduce the error but tomorrow. Do you think its best to open a new question because of that, or would it be OK to edit my first post and add a second part to it? So far, thanks for your help!

Comment: @skypjack: [according to this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), initializing a temp variable in the `capture-list` of a lambda was added in C++14.  Lambdas were added in C++11, where in that version only existing variables can be captured, so you would have to do something more like this instead: `auto param = foo2(); foo1([param](){ foo3(param); });` which would be simplified as this: `auto param = foo2(); foo1([=](){ foo3(param); });` which would be simplified as this: `foo1([](){ foo3(foo2()); });`

Comment: @user7408924 I'd rather open a second question. Something like - _ok, now I know how to do that, this is my code and it compiles on my laptop, what's wrong with the Arduino?_

Comment: @RemyLebeau Everything is right. Anyway there isn't the `C++11` tag to the question, thus I assumed C++14 was good enough. That's all. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack: don't assume that. Many developers still haven't adopted C++11, let alone C++14 or C++17. Unless a question is tagged otherwise, assume earlier versions. Or at least provide solutions for multiple versions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see your point. As soon as I turn on the laptop, I'll update the question. Thank you.

Comment: From what I have read the current Arduino version *does* support C++11, however I am not sure about C++14